# 'onmousedown' not being called in JavaScript 

Tags: javascript, multithreading, event-handling, onmousedown

In Javascript, I want to create a handler for a mouse click. Then, I want to be able to "busy-wait" for a few seconds before running the next line of code.* But in the "busy-wait", I want to still be able to process the mouse click events.

Why will the following code run the `while` loop entirely and THEN activate the handler? (as in, why doesn't the mouse click handler event ever get called in the middle of the busy-wait `while` loop?)

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p id="debugMessageElement"> </p>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            canvas=document.createElement("canvas")
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            canvas.width = 840;
            canvas.height = 560;
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);

            var mouse_input = function(event){
                document.getElementById("debugMessageElement").innerHTML = event.pageX + ", " + event.pageY + "<br />"
            }

            canvas.onmousedown = mouse_input;

            timeallowed = 3
            start = Date.now()
            while(true){
                now = Date.now()
                delta = now - start
                if(delta >= timeallowed*1000){
                    document.write("" + timeallowed + " seconds has passed")
                    break;
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

*The reason that I'm designing my code like the above is ultimately because I want to do something like this:

```
for(p in person){
    for(t in person[p].shirts){
        busy_wait_5_seconds() //However, I want to process mouse clicks in these five seconds.
        //THEN move on to the next shirt... After five seconds...
    }
}
```

P.S. if you're going to test this code, please note that I used the HTML5 canvas, so some browsers might not work?

Comment: You're missing semi-colons all over, particularly on your `debugMessageElement` line. Could be causing problems..

Comment: sorry about that. Javascript actually does not care about semicolons, so that is unfortunately not the problem (i wish it were that simple!). I am used to Ruby and Python so i do not to use semicolons. But thanks for the tip. I am slowly converting over to JS

Comment: Javascript DOES care about semi-colons, but some browsers do not and they will insert missing semi-colons at their discretion. I highly suggest you adhere to the specification and explicitly use semi-colons where they are meant to be placed.

Comment: do you happen to know if the auto semi-colon insertion will mess up my code for certain browsers?

but regardless, you made a good point to adhere to the specs, and i think i'll get to a point where i'll eventually start using them more explicitly. Thanks for the feedback, and if there are any other tips for a new JS guy, plz do share!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript has only a single thread. If you do a while-true loop, it will essentially freeze the entire page until the code stops running.

To wait a certain time before executing some code, you should use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout). The final solution to your problem is a little more complicated than that though - you would need a recursive setTimeout to process the loop.

edit: Here's something I quickly whipped up which should solve your nested loop with waiting in the sub loop: http://jsfiddle.net/t4gsR/ - It may go a bit over your head if you're still a beginner though, but press "run" on the top menu and see it work :)

Comment: I looked at setTimeout and setInterval, however, i wasn't sure how to apply it exactly. i could do a recursive setTimeout, but doesn't that screw up the nested for-loops?

Comment: This. Something is terribly wrong when I see a question tagged both "javascript" and "multithreading".

Comment: yeah... i know, javascript is not multi-threaded, and so i want to learn the "javascript way" of implementing the problem

Comment: @DavidT. I added an example in the jsfiddle link for solving the nested loop thing :)

Comment: This is good. i somewhat get it (not fully) and could use this. Thanks!!